# How do I add multiple values under a specific column in Tkinter using ttk.Treeview

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using the subprocess library to capture the output of a windows command. What I'm trying to do is to add the output under a specific column in ttk.Treeview.

```
programs = []
cmd = f"wmic startup get caption"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
out, err = p.communicate()
out = out.decode()
programs.append(out)
for apps in programs:
    apps = apps.strip()
    tree_sec.insert('', 'end', values=apps)  

tree_sec = ttk.Treeview(tab2, show='headings')

tree_sec['columns'] = ('software_name', 'User', 'blah')

tree_sec.column("#0", width=200)
tree_sec.column("software_name", width=200)
tree_sec.column("User", width=200)
tree_sec.column("blah", width=200)

tree_sec.heading("software_name", text="Software")
tree_sec.heading("User", text="User")
tree_sec.heading("blah", text="blah")
tree_sec.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

What this does is that it iterates through the output and adds each line into the different columns, what I'm trying to achieve is to just add it under the software_name column instead of distributing it under different columns.

Comment: Since `software_name` is the first column (excluding tree column `#0`), you can try `tree_sec.insert(..., values=(apps,))`.

Comment: @acw1668 That kinda worked, but as soon as I click the first value in the column it goes back to displaying the data horizontally

Comment: What do you mean by *"click the first value in the column"*?

Comment: Did you try to print out the content of `programs`? Is it what you expected?

Comment: @acw1668 the output of subprocess is somehow messing with how treeview displays items, because I used a normal list and it works. I tried stripping for characters but it doesn't work. I noticed that the out of subprocess has a lot of /r/r/r/r.

Comment: If you know the output of the subprocess, then you should know how to split it to what you want.